# Doctrine query error unknow column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine in my Symfony3 project. I'm using the entity manager to get my data from the database but I have an unexpected error which seems to be generated by doctrine.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.date AS date_2, t0.comment AS comment_3, t0.viewed AS viewed_4, t0.error_count AS error_count_5, t0.of_id AS of_id_6, t0.checkpoint_id AS checkpoint_id_7, t8.id AS id_9, t8.name AS name_10, t8.description AS description_11, t8.deleted_at AS deleted_at_12, t8.factory_id AS factory_id_13, t0.operateur_id AS operateur_id_15, t0.factory_id AS factory_id_16 FROM app_check_set t0 LEFT JOIN app_checkpoint t8 ON t0.checkpoint_id = t14.id AND ((t14.deleted_at IS NULL)) WHERE t0.factory_id = ? ORDER BY t0.date DESC LIMIT 5' with params [3]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't14.id' in 'on clause'").

**As I'm not creating the query myself, i would like to know where is this error coming from ? Is it related with my entity configuration ?**

The problem is when I want to get my entities `Checkset` :

```
public function notificationsAction(Request $request){
    $user           = $this->getUser();
    $em             = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Home:notifications.html.twig', array(
        'notifications' => $em->getRepository('AppBundle:CheckSet')->findBy(array('factory' => $user->getFactory()->getId()), array('date' => 'desc'), 5),
        'count'         => count($em->getRepository('AppBundle:CheckSet')->findBy(array('factory' => $user->getFactory()->getId(), 'viewed' => false)))
    ));
}
```

My entities are like this :

**CheckSet:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * CheckSet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_check_set")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CheckSetRepository")
 */
class CheckSet
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckElementResult", mappedBy="checkSet", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $checkElementResult;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckElementResultObservation", mappedBy="checkSet", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $observations;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Of", inversedBy="checkSet")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="of_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $of;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckPoint", inversedBy="checkSet", fetch="EAGER") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="checkpoint_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $checkPoint;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="checkSet")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operateur_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $operateur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default" : false})
     */
    protected $viewed = FALSE;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $errorCount;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Factory", inversedBy="checkSet")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="factory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $factory;

    public function __construct($gamme = null, $of = null, $user = null){
        $this->checkElementResult  = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->observations        = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->date                = new \DateTime();
        $this->errorCount          = 0;
        if ($gamme != null){
            $this->checkPoint = $gamme;
        }
        if ($of != null){
            $this->of = $of;
        }
        if ($user != null){
            $this->operateur    = $user;
            $this->factory      = $user->getFactory();
        }

    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setDate($date){
        $this->date = $date;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(){
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setErrorCount($errorCount){
        $this->errorCount = $errorCount;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getErrorCount(){
        return $this->errorCount;
    }

    public function setComment($comment){
        $this->comment = $comment;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment(){
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setOperateur(User $operateur){
        $this->operateur = $operateur;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOperateur(){
        return $this->operateur;
    }

    public function setOf(Of $of){
        $this->of = $of;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOf(){
        return $this->of;
    }

    public function setFactory(Factory $factory){
        $this->factory = $factory;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFactory(){
        return $this->factory;
    }

    public function setCheckPoint(Checkpoint $checkPoint){
        $this->checkPoint = $checkPoint;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCheckPoint(){
        return $this->checkPoint;
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------CheckElementResult*/
    public function addCheckElementResult(CheckElementResult $cke){
        $this->checkElementResult[] = $cke;
        $cke->setCheckSet($this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCheckElementResult(CheckElementResult $cke){
        $this->checkElementResult->removeElement($cke);
    }

    public function getcheckElementResult(){
        return $this->checkElementResult;
    } 

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------observations*/
    public function addObservations(CheckElementResultObservation $cke){
        $this->observations[] = $cke;
        $cke->setCheckSet($this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeObservations(CheckElementResultObservation $cke){
        $this->observations->removeElement($cke);
    }

    public function getObservations(){
        return $this->observations;
    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------VIEWED*/
    public function setViewed($viewed){
        $this->viewed = $viewed;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getViewed(){
        return $this->viewed;
    }

    public function isViewed(){
        return $this->viewed;
    }

    public function countErrors(){
        $err = 0;
        foreach ($this->checkElementResult as $key => $ckeR) {
            foreach ($ckeR->getCheckElement()->getAlert() as $key => $alert) {
                if(         $alert->getOperator() == "==" && $ckeR->getValue() == $alert->getValue()){
                    $err++;
                }elseif (   $alert->getOperator() == "!=" && $ckeR->getValue() != $alert->getValue()) {
                    $err++;
                }elseif (   $alert->getOperator() == "<" && $ckeR->getValue() < $alert->getValue()) {
                    $err++;
                }elseif (   $alert->getOperator() == ">" && $ckeR->getValue() > $alert->getValue()) {
                    $err++;
                }elseif (   $alert->getOperator() == "<=" && $ckeR->getValue() <= $alert->getValue()) {
                    $err++;
                }elseif (   $alert->getOperator() == ">=" && $ckeR->getValue() >= $alert->getValue()) {
                    $err++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $err;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->of->getName().' '.$this->checkPoint->getName();
    }

}
```

**CheckPoint:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Checkpoint
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_checkpoint")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CheckpointRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Checkpoint
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckElement", mappedBy="checkpoint",cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $checkElements;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Operation", mappedBy="checkpoint",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $operation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Factory", inversedBy="checkpoints")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="factory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckSet", mappedBy="checkPoint")
     */
    private $checkSet;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckListOf", mappedBy="checkPoint")
     */
    private $checkListOf;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->checkElements    = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setDescription($description){
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function getFactory(){
      return $this->factory;
    }

    public function setFactory($factory){
      $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------Checkelements*/
    public function addCheckElement(CheckElement $cke){
        $this->checkElements[] = $cke;
        $cke->setCheckpoint($this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCheckElement(CheckElement $cke){
        $this->checkElements->removeElement($cke);
    }

    public function getCheckElements(){
        return $this->checkElements;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

The problem could be because of the soft delete but I'm not sure ... The controller I'm calling (`notificationsAction`) is embed in my header.

**In this page (the notifications area) I want to display objects which may have been deleted. The problem happend when the `checkpoint` I want to display (the one related to the Checkset objects) has been deleted**

```
<!-- NOTIFICATIONS -->
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Home:notifications', {'request': app.request})) }}
```

Comment: Can you run `bin/console d:s:v`? Is the output `[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.`?

Comment: Can you add the version of doctrine you are using?

Comment: [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5"

Comment: Can you add the Factory entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889754/doctrine-generating-query-with-wrong-table-alias).

Your class name is **Checkpoint** and I guess the file is named **checkpoint.php** (note that if you are developing on windows, the filename is case-insensitive). All are **lowercase**.

In your CheckSet class you have

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckPoint", inversedBy="checkSet", fetch="EAGER") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="checkpoint_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $checkPoint;
```

The **targetEntity** is to **"AppBundle\Entity\CheckPoint"** with capital **P**.

The issue is that because of this, doctrine create a new alias for a new table (the php comparison is case sensitive [github link](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php#L1517)).

To solve this, change your class name and file to **CheckPoint** with capital **P**:

```
class CheckPoint
{
```

Comment: The class name was actualy : Checkpoint that was my issues, I putted targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CheckPoint" and you were right, the class names were not matching ("Checkpoint" != "CheckPoint"). I had to change the targetEntity to : targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Checkpoint". Thanks !